# Python binascii help in the code at the documentation

Tags: python-3.x

What does `print('crc32 = {:#010x}'.format(crc))` means in Python 3.8? Link is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html). I am not able to understand it. All the solution and link is accepted. What does `{:#010x}` mean, please define.

Answer (score 0):

```
{:#010x}
```

According to the [formatting spec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec)

`#` -> use alternate conversion for integers (instead of the `repr`)

`0` -> use `0` for filling the start

`10` -> width of the final string to achieve (the string will be padded with 0s to achieve this length)

`x` -> use the hex (base-16) representation of the integer argument (this is why we needed the `#` at the start)